# Pass pointer to string

Tags: arrays, pointers, printf, strtok

I have a pointer and I pass it to a string using sprintf but when I try to access elements in the string I have trouble.

What I want is if I have a pointer to the string `abcde` to create a new string

```
seg[5]="a,b,c,d,e"
```

such that when I call `seg[0]` I get `"a".`

I have some code below

```
     char *pch5;
     char seg1[128];

     pch5=strtok(seg,",");
                                if(pch5!=NULL){
                                sprintf(seg1,"%s",pch5);
                                    printf("%s",seg1[0]);
                                }
```

Comment: This may help: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printf is wrong, you are using the format %s, but what you want is %c.

Answer (score 0):

seg[5] here holds string "a,b,c" only, because strlen("a,b,c") == 5. But if you want the full string use is as following:

seg[] = "a,b,c,d,e";